# CSS custom li p links

Tags: jquery, html, css

Seems really weird becouse last time i trying put same styling and works perfect, but now not working. My HTML looks like that:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span><img src="test1.png"></span>TEST!<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
<a rel="nofollow" href="../test1"><li><p><img src="/assets/flags/test1.png"> Test1</p></li></a>
</ul>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu > a > li > p {
    clear: both;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    white-space: nowrap;
transition: color .2s ease;
}

.dropdown-menu > a:focus > li > p,
.dropdown-menu > a:hover > li > p {
color: #ff7500 !important;
text-decoration: none;
transition: color .2s ease;
```

thanks for helping guys! really like stackoverflow community!

Comment: `li` elements must be *inside* `ul` elements , see docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Comment: `<ul>` should have only `<li>` as a child, not `<a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```css
.dropdown-menu > li > a > p {
    clear: both;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #555;
    white-space: nowrap;
    transition: color .2s ease;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus > p,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover > p{
color:#ff7500  !important;
text-decoration: none;
transition: color .2s ease;
border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span><img src="test1.png"></span>TEST!<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a rel="nofollow" href="../test1"><p><img src="/assets/flags/test1.png"> Test1</p></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your HTML structure updated with a more correct structure :

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span><img src="test1.png"></span>TEST!
      <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a rel="nofollow" href="../test1">
      <img src="/assets/flags/test1.png"> Test1
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g0dchyjL/2/)

The `ul` structure was incorrect in your example, see docs here :

**Docs :**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul

Be also careful about the difference between `inline` and `block` elements, see docs here :

**Docs :**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements#Block-level_vs._inline

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements